# Should I use verb or noun when talking about time it took to do something?

Tags: verbs, nouns, time

An example from the computer science. Which one is "more" correct `compilation time`  or `compile time`? Google translate suggests `compile time`. However in similar scenario with "generate" google translate suggests `generation time` not `generate time`. Is there any simple rule to follow?

Comment: Follow the customs of the community that uses technical terms like this.

Comment: I would suggest *compilation time* to mean elapsed time during compilation, and *compile time* to mean that stage in software development.